# How to add my own server code to webpack-dev-server execution

Tags: angularjs, express, angular, webpack

Basic question about how to add my own server-based code to webpack-dev-server, or alternatively, replace webpack-dev-server with express (giving up hot module reloading).  I expected to find a file called something like server.js, that I can add my own code to.  This is a basic question, as every non-static application needs their own server code, but I haven't found a straight forward way of doing it.  I'm using [Angular 2 Webpack Starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter).  I would expect it to be easy to subsequently drop webpack-dev-server for straight express when going to production.

Comment: The dev server is for front-end development only. Production builds are served by your own server implementation, e.g. I serve my Webpack production bundle using HapiJS + Inert, but develop with webpack-dev-server. You should never use the webpack server for production environments.

Comment: Understood that webpack server should not be used for production (hence the last sentence).  The question is about, when doing development starting with the front end, but then adding in back-end development, it is not clear where the back-end development code goes.  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can still use Express *and* have hot reloading, by using [`webpack-dev-middleware`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware) and [`webpack-hot-middleware`](https://github.com/glenjamin/webpack-hot-middleware).

Both middleware should not be loaded in production, for which you can use something like this:

```
// Webpack (when not running in production mode)
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
  const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');
  const webpackConfig        = require('./webpack.config');
  const compiler             = require('webpack')(webpackConfig);

  app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
    noInfo     : true,
    publicPath : webpackConfig.output.publicPath
  }));
  app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));
}
```

(`app` is an Express instance)